# Excel formula to calculate and find a (sum) number within a range of numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Excel screenshot

[image: 1]

I have a figure in R209 and I need to figure out that difference / look for that value in column F. So in this case, the figure in R209 is a difference between F202 and F203

Is there an excel formula that I can use to figure this out for?

Comment: If you mean that R209 = F202+F203 (F202 is a negative value), then simply use that formula... Or do you ask for something else?

Comment: It's a large set of data so is there a formula that can point to F202+F203 and say that's where the figure in R209 lies so excel would lookup in column F and point me to those 2 cells F202+F203

Comment: Not on the basis of your screenshot, since it could just as easily be `F206 + F207` and, considering the value in `H207` I think most people looking at your data would believe that `F206+F207` make up your total.